# Likelihood ratio of non-trivial cycles in an inhomogeneous random square lattice graph embedded on a toroidal surface

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, at.algebraic-topology, random-graphs, percolation

Consider a square lattice (random) graph $G$ embedded on a toroidal surface. Each edge $(i, j)$ of the graph has an associated likelihood probability $p_{ij}$. The probabilities $p_{ij}$ come from a *probability distribution* with some general parameters like mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma$, etc.

I'd like to study the likelihood ratio of homologically *non-trivial* cycles to homologically *trivial* cycles in this setting and ideally set some reasonable upper bounds on this likelihood ratio. Is there any relevant research related to this?

I've found that people have studied [inhomogenous percolation models](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0509020) in random graphs where they use a method based on generating functions to derive the critical percolation threshold. This is not the same problem but it at least smells similar.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of a question you would like to consider? Suppose we have an $n\times n$ lattice torus - if I understand the terminology right, a homologically non-trivial cycle must contain at least $n$ edges, while a homologically trivial cycle could contain just 4 edges? Or are you interested more in comparing cycles of similar lengths?

Comment: @JamesMartin Thanks very much for pointing this out. In the scenario I'm considering, I'm interested specifically in cycles that have at least $n$ edges, whether homologically trivial or not. But the first scenario that you mention would also be interesting to know about.

Comment: If there are any results about the second question you mention, where the cycles have similar lengths or the same length, I'd be glad to know about that. Even when $p_{ij} = p$ is a constant. :-)