# Counting homologically non-trivial and trivial cycles in $n \times n$ square lattice torus of a given length $l \geq n$

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

This *should* be a fairly standard question but I can't really seem to find a reference.

Consider an $n \times n$ square lattice torus $\mathbb T$. Given a length $l \geq n$, what is the number of homologically *non-trivial* cycles of length $l$ on $\mathbb T$, and what is the number of homologically *trivial* cycles of length $l$? Can we tell something about their ratio? (By "length", I mean the number of edges the cycle contains.)

**N.B.** I'm asking this as a very special case of [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428208/likelihood-ratio-of-non-trivial-cycles-in-an-inhomogeneous-random-square-lattice). It's surprising to me that I couldn't find any results on this from an hour-long Googling. Whereas, Bollobas et al. apparently have considered much [harder-looking questions](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eodonnell/papers/eliminating-cycles.pdf).

Comment: Well, you're counting 1-cycles outside of image of cellular differential and 1-cycles in its image intersected with an $\ell^1$-ball, which is just cube; so up to a constant that should be computable (rough estimate on Lipshitz constants from approximate SVD probably should be enough) ratio is roughly $l^{n^2+1} - l^{n^2 -1}$ to $l^{n^2 -1}$. So it's just $l^2$ asymptotically for $l >> n$ in favor of nontrivial cycles. Is there anything intricate I'm not seeing? (of course, I said nothing for interesting range when $l \approx n$)

Comment: ...and if you care only about geometric cycles, i. e. with values in ${-1, 0, 1}$ you could do pretty much the same over $\Bbb Z/3$ and obtain reasonable estimates from plain linear algebra as well.

Comment: @DenisT. This sounds like a very good idea, except I don't really know what you mean by estimating Lipchitz constants from approximate SVD. Could you perhaps explain how exactly you're getting your estimates of $l^{n^2 + 1}$ and $l^{n^2 - 1}$? Indeed, I'm only interested in geometric cycles and that too over $\mathbb Z/2$, but even the linear algebra way leads to a complicated combinatorics problem.